# Run a task for N second in C

Tags: c, timer, process

I'm trying to complete an assignment for uni and I'm encountering an issue. I want to create something like a "timer" for my program. What I mean is that I want to run the program for 30 seconds, and after those have passed I want to print some stats before closing it. Since it is a process related project I would like this timer to be passed to the child processes as well if possible. Here is some pseudo-code of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
/* Timer starts from here */
    - forking childs
    - child execute
    - other actions
/* Timer finishes here */

Printing statistics
exit(0)
```

I tried reading up something on alarm, time and others but I wasn't able to find anything that could help me. Hope you can help me out and thanks in advance.

Comment: use `alarm()` in parents, use `wait()` in parents to wait for child to finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to read the man pages of `alarm()`. check the man page of `alarm`

```
  unsigned int alarm(unsigned int seconds);
```

What alarm returns ? *alarm()  returns the number of seconds remaining until any previously scheduled alarm was due to be delivered, or zero if there
       was no previously scheduled alarm.*

you can set multiple `alarm()` for `N` seconds, but not all at a time.

Here is the simple code to understand alarm().

```
#include<signal.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int al = 5;
void my_isr(int n)
{
        static int count = 0;//count variable

        if(n == 17) {
                /** this child will execute if child completer before 5 seconds**/
                int ret = wait(0);//releases child resources
                printf("child %d completed \n",ret);
        }

        if(n == 14) {
                printf("in sigalarm isr \n");
                /** do task here **/
                if(count<3) {
                        alarm(5);// after doing some task set another alarm
                }
                count++;
        }
}
int main()
{
        if(fork()==0)
        {
                printf("child : pid = %d ppid  = %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
                /** letting the child to run for 20 seconds **/
                sleep(20);
                printf("child exits after task over \n");
                exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
                alarm(al);//setting 5 seconds timer for child to finish job

                signal(SIGALRM,my_isr);
                /** to avoid child to become zombie. when child completes parents will receive SIGCHLD signal, upon receving this parent needs to free the resources associated with it using wait */ 
                signal(SIGCHLD,my_isr);
                while(1);//to keep main process alive for observation
        }
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: This is already helping me lots, but something I'd like to ask you is how would i be able to do this for a number of time? I need to run a timer every 5 seconds for 3 times but when I try to put the function in a cycle it just does it once.

Comment: @BryanShtjefni you can set the multiple alarm for running timer every n seconds right ?

Comment: @BryanShtjefni I edited my answer,check it. Is that you want or anything else.